# How make Array.Sort case-sensitive?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, case-sensitive

Basically I need to sort a list of strings, but there are ***lower case***, ***upper case*** and ***numerics*** in the strings. Currently when it sorts them it values `a` and `A` as the same letter so:

```
acfgh
aztyu
Ahtwm
```

would be sorted to:

```
acfgh
Ahtwm
aztyu
```

But I want it to rank capitals before lower case (and numerics before capitals) so that I would get:

```
Ahtwm
acfgh
aztyu
```

I'd rather still use the methods already contained in the library than create my own quicksort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel :-)

Suppose an array of string named myArray:

`Array.Sort(myArray, StringComparer.Ordinal)`

will do the trick (capitals before lower case and numerics before capitals).

Example:

```
Dim str = String() = {"aa", "Aa", "1a", "1A"}
Array.Sort(str, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

Output:

```
1A
1a
Aa
aa
```